# Raven's SentryHandler is suppressing StreamHandler output to file

Tags: python, logging, sentry, raven

I have a plain python (non-Django) project where I'm trying to [tie Raven into the logging setup](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/logging.html).

Under our current setup, we use a simple logging config:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='long detailed format',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
```

The output is then redirected to a log file; this produces a nice, verbose log that we can look through when we need to.

We now want to add Raven's error logging, tying it into our current logging setup so that `logging.error` calls **also** result in a message being sent to the Sentry server.  Using the following code:

```
from raven import Client
from raven.conf import setup_logging
from raven.handlers.logging import SentryHandler

raven = Client(environ.get('SENTRYURL', ''), site='SITE')
setup_logging(SentryHandler(raven, level=logging.ERROR))
```

Errors are being successfully sent to Sentry, but I'm now getting only a single line of file output:

```
DEBUG: Configuring Raven for host: <DSN url>
```

All other file output -- from `logging.debug` to `logging.error` -- is being suppressed.

If I comment the `setup_logging` line, I get file output but no Sentry errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a case of sloppy code.  We had some hack elsewhere in the startup execution path that re-initialized the logging:

```
logging.root.removeHandler(logging.root.handlers[0]) # Undo previous basicConfig
logging.basicConfig(format='same long format',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
```

However, since `logging.basicConfig` doesn't do anything if `logging.root` has existing handlers, this simply removed the stream handler, leaving the sentry handler, and caused `basicConfig` to then act as no-op, meaning we lost our StreamHandler altogether.

Removing these lines and having only one `basicConfig` and a `setup_logging` call worked.